# Mouse hover in jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I added this code for mouse hover *(status_id varies)*:

```
$("#test"+status_id).mouseover(function(){
   $('.data'+status_id+'a').show();
});
```

but, it will not show the mouse hover. But adding an alert to print the class like :

```
alert("#test"+status_id)
$("#test"+status_id).mouseover(function(){
   $('.data'+status_id+'a').show();
});
```

caused the function to start working properly. I don't know why the difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you able to get alert inside mouseover()?

Comment: In $(".data" + status_id …) you are calling a class, not an id. If that does not helps, show more code.

Comment: you are create any div dynamically?

Comment: Ya disha in firefox not in chrome

Comment: It seems problem in line `$('.data'+status_id+'a').show();`

Comment: That not problem disha. Because i remove that code and put alert only inside mouse hover condition its also didnt work

Comment: can you paste html code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this part: `$('.data'+status_id+'a')` create before after you call it. use like this:

```
$(document).on("mouseover","#test"+status_id, function () {

   $('.data'+status_id+'a').show();

});
```

Note:
I hope this `$('.data'+status_id+'a').show();` mean somthing like this:

```
<a class="data5" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#test"+status_id).hover(function () {
   $('.data'+status_id+'a').show();
   alert('test');
});
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it said *why* to use `.hover()` instead of `.mouseover()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the problem is that your code was running before the browser was ready for it (and the alert delayed it enough to work).  You should pretty much always surround your jQuery code in a check for the browser being ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#test"+status_id).mouseover(function(){
        $('.data'+status_id+'a').show();
    });

}
```

many people prefer, (and thus you will frequently see), the "shorthand" version:

```
$(function() {

    $("#test"+status_id).mouseover(function(){
        $('.data'+status_id+'a').show();
    });

}
```